# Github Action Unexpected input(s) Warning

Tags: github-actions

I'm getting this warning after my workflow complete running.How can I fix this please? by the way,I am running Github Action with terragrunt

```
action.yml

- name: 'Terragrunt Init'
        uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
          tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'init'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
          tf_actions_comment: true
```

```
Unexpected input(s) 'tf_action_version', valid inputs are ['entryPoint', 'args', 'tf_actions_subcommand', 'tf_actions_binary', 'tf_actions_version', 'tg_actions_version', 'tf_actions_cli_credentials_hostname', 'tf_actions_cli_credentials_token', 'tf_actions_comment', 'tf_actions_working_dir', 'tf_actions_fmt_write']

``
```

Comment: It looks like an indentation issue. Could you share the repository workflow file url to check it from the source?

Comment: Note that the warning mentions "action" rather than "actions". I can't see the singular version in your yml though..?

Comment: @rethab  I had action instead of actions in my workflow.thank you its fixed now